# string tokenizer in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, stringtokenizer

I like to tokenize a string to characters and store the tokens in a string array. I am trying to use following code which is not working as I am using C notation to access the array. What needs to be changed in place of travel path[i]?

```
NSArray *tokanizedTravelPath= [[NSArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; [travelPath length]; i++) {
    tokanizedTravelPath[i]= [travelPath characterAtIndex:i];
```

Comment: Splitting a string into individual characters is not "tokenizing" it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a NSMutableArray to set every element of the array (otherwise you can't change its objects).Also, you can only insert objects in the array, so you can:
- Insert a NSString containing the character;
- Use a C-style array instead.
This is how to do with the NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *tokanizedTravelPath= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<[travelPath length]; i++) 
{
    [tokanizedTravelPath insertObject: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", [travelPath characterAtIndex:i]] atIndex: i];
}
```

Comment: This code wont work, as the for-condition is false. see my post.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't see it.Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store `unichar`s in an `NSArray*`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? An `NSString*` is already a great representation for a collection of `unichar`s, and you already have one of those.

Answer (score 1):

I count 3 errors in your code, I explain them at the end of my answer.
First I want to show you a better approach to split a sting into it characters.

---

While I agree with Kevin that an `NSString` is a great representation of unicode characters already, you can use this block-based code to split it into substrings and save it to an array.

Form the docs:

> [`enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW86)
>   Enumerates the 
>   substrings of the specified type in the specified range of the string.

```
NSString *hwlloWord = @"Hello World";
NSMutableArray *charArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[hwlloWord enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [hwlloWord length])
                              options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                           usingBlock:^(NSString *substring,
                                        NSRange substringRange,
                                        NSRange enclosingRange,
                                        BOOL *stop)
{
    [charArray addObject:substring];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", charArray);
```

Output:

```
(
    H,
    e,
    l,
    l,
    o,
    " ",
    W,
    o,
    r,
    l,
    d
)
```

---

But actually your problems are of another nature:

- An `NSArray` is immutable. Once instantiated, it cannot be altered. For mutable array, you use the `NSArray` subclass [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
- Also, `characterAtIndex` does not return an object, but a primitive type — but those can't be saved to an `NSArray`. You have to wrap it into an `NSString` or some other representation.

  You could use `substringWithRange` instead.

  ```
  NSMutableArray *tokanizedTravelPath= [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i=0; i < [hwlloWord length]; ++i) {
      NSLog(@"%@",[hwlloWord substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]);
      [tokanizedTravelPath addObject:[hwlloWord substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
  }
  ```
- Also your for-loop is wrong, the for-loop condition is not correct. it must be `for (int i=0; i < [travelPath length]; i++)`